# Why is this only showing my hand and not the dealers hand? also it tells me i busted no matter what

Tags: java

// This looks 100% to me but for some reason it only shows my hand, the math is correct but tells me I have busted every hand as well. Thank you for any help you have.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BlackjackTest 
{

String type;
int currentcard;
int total = 0;
        static int dealertotal = 0;
        static int playertotal = 0;

        Random ran = new Random();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        public BlackjackTest(String player)
        {
            type = player;
            System.out.println(" Game Has Started");
            deal();
            game();
        }

        void displayCard()
        {
            currentcard = ran.nextInt(14);
            while(currentcard == 0)
            {
                currentcard = ran.nextInt(14);
            }
            switch(currentcard)
            {
            case 11:
                System.out.println(type + " Drew a jack");
                total = total + 10;
                System.out.println(type + " Current Total: " + total);
                break;
            case 12:
                System.out.println(type + " Drew a queen");
                total = total + 10;
                System.out.println(type + " Current Total: " + total);
                break;
            case 13:
                System.out.println(type + " Drew a king");
                total = total + 10;
                System.out.println(type + " Current Total: " + total);
                break;
            case 14:
                System.out.println(type + " Drew an ace");
                total = total + 11;
                System.out.println(type + " Current Total: " + total);
                break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(type + " Drew a " + currentcard);
                    total = total + currentcard;
                    System.out.println(type + " Current Total: " + total);

            }

        }

        void deal()
        {
            System.out.println( "First Card is ");
            displayCard();
            System.out.println("Second Card is");
            displayCard();
        }

        void game()
        {
            if (total <=21)
            {
                if (total <= 21)
                {
                    if(!(type.equals("Dealer")))
                    {
                        System.out.println(" Would you like to Hit (yes)");
                        if (scan.nextLine().equals("yes"))
                        {
                            displayCard();
                            game();

                        }
                        else
                            System.out.println("Your Total: " + total);
                            playertotal = total;

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println (type + " Busted: " + total);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if(type.equals("Dealer"))
            {
                if ((total < 17 && total <= 21 || total < playertotal))
                        {
                    displayCard();
                    game();
                        }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Your Total: " + total);
                    playertotal = total;
                }

        }
        else
        {


            System.out.println ( type + " Busted: " + total);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(type.equals("Dealer"))
        {
            if ((total < 17 && total <= 21) || total < playertotal)
            {
                displayCard();
                game();
            }
            else
            {
                if(total <21)
                dealertotal = total ;
            }
        }
  }


  void WhoWon() { 

  if(dealertotal == 0)
  {
      System.out.println("Dealer Busted");
  }
  if (playertotal == 0)
  {
      System.out.println(" Player Busted");
  }
  if (dealertotal > playertotal)
  {
      System.out.println("Dealer Won");
  }
  else if(dealertotal < playertotal)
  {
      System.out.println("Player won");
  }
      if (dealertotal == playertotal)
      {
          System.out.println ( " Push (Draw)");
      }
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
      BlackjackTest Ryan = new BlackjackTest ("Ryan");
      BlackjackTest Dealer = new BlackjackTest("Dealer");
      Ryan.WhoWon();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are there two `if (total <= 21)` in method game()... I think a mistake?

Comment: You should probably elaborate on this question. It is not so much fun to just read a code and try to figure out what it would like to implement and then figure out the errors.

Comment: Please rephrase your question title. If you have a technical issue, then ask a technical question.

Comment: Check your game logic again.. I'm 99% sure it's erroneous

Comment: You are creating 2 Players, but just ask one for the result and never tell them to play together. Is this right?

Comment: its a blackjack game basically. Accept im trying to get two players not just myself. Idk where i went wrong in the code or i would make it more simple myself

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

you are creating `Ryan` object first from main, and you constructor looks like this.

```
public BlackjackTest(String player)
    {
        type = player;
        System.out.println(" Game Has Started");
        deal();
        game();
    }
```

Now in `game` method you have one condition where you are checking if player total in less than 21 or if player is a dealer..

```
  if (total <=21)
    {
         ....
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println (type + " Busted: " + total);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if(type.equals("Dealer"))
    {
       ......
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ( type + " Busted: " + total);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

and as you see, from both else part, you are just printing that you are busted and exiting programme. That is why it is not even going to create `Dealer` object.

Remove both else block and your program will start creating `Dealer` object

Comment: No, that takes away everything and makes its come out ryan has busted without even typing anything.